# Cannot apply inter-pod affinity to Airflow scheduler

Tags: kubernetes, airflow, kubernetes-helm, azure-aks

I am encountering a weird behavior when I try to attach `podAffinity` to the **Scheduler deployment from the official Airflow helm chart**, like:

```
  affinity:
    podAffinity:
      requiredDuringSchedulingIgnoredDuringExecution:
      - labelSelector:
          matchExpressions:
          - key: app 
            operator: In
            values:
            - postgresql
        topologyKey: "kubernetes.io/hostname"
```

With an example Deployment to which the `podAffinity` should "hook up" to:

```
metadata:
  name: {{ template "postgresql.fullname" . }}
  labels:
    app: postgresql
    chart: {{ template "postgresql.chart" . }}
    release: {{ .Release.Name | quote }}
    heritage: {{ .Release.Service | quote }}
spec:
  serviceName: {{ template "postgresql.fullname" . }}-headless
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: postgresql
      release: {{ .Release.Name | quote }}
  template:
    metadata:
      name: {{ template "postgresql.fullname" . }}
      labels:
        app: postgresql
        chart: {{ template "postgresql.chart" . }}
```

Which results in:

```
NotTriggerScaleUp: pod didn't trigger scale-up: 1 node(s) didn't match pod affinity/anti-affinity, 1 node(s) didn't match pod affinity rules
```

**However, applying the same `podAffinity` config to the Webserver deployment works just fine. Plus, changing the example Deployment to a vanilla nginx manifested itself in the outcome.**

It does not seem to be any resource limitation issue since I already tried various configs, every time with the same result.
I do not use any custom configurations apart from node affinity.

Has anyone encounter the same or has any idea what I might do wrong?

**Setup:**

- AKS cluster
- Airflow helm chart 1.1.0
- Airflow 1.10.15 (but I don't think this matters)
- kubectl client (1.22.1) and server (1.20.7)

**Links to Airflow charts:**

- [Scheduler](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/main/chart/templates/scheduler/scheduler-deployment.yaml)
- [Webserver](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/main/chart/templates/webserver/webserver-deployment.yaml)

Comment: What labels are on postgres pod?

Comment: @Hitobat I just updated, but I am more than certain there doesn´t lie the issue since it works for the webserver..

Comment: Could you share Webserver deployment? What is the difference between that and your Postrgres?

Comment: @kkopczak. I use the official airflow chart. The postgres is not of importance since I can reproduce this issue when trying to use *podAffinity* to any other pods (e.g. I tried a basic NGINX which resulted in the same behavior). I edited my issue for clarification.

Comment: I wasn't able to reproduce this issue on my GKE cluster (I used the same affinity configuration as yours). In order to allow me to further investigate your issue, please provide following information:

1. The entire `values.yaml` file (especially the configuration for `scheduler`).
2. All `Events` for the `scheduler` Pod (including the `Type`,`Reason` and `Message` fields).
3. The node affinity configuration you mentioned earlier.
4. The output from the `kubectl top nodes` command (execute it when problem occurs).
5. Do you use cluster autoscaler ?

Comment: @kkopczak there was something else wrong with my setup, seemingly. I switched to NodeAffinity and got it working so I didn´t bother to investigate any further. thanks for your wiki tho!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've recreated this scenario on my GKE cluster and I've decided to provide a Community Wiki answer to show that the [podAffinity](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/scheduling-eviction/assign-pod-node/#inter-pod-affinity-and-anti-affinity) on the [Scheduler](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/main/chart/templates/scheduler/scheduler-deployment.yaml) works as expected.
I will describe step by step how I tested it below.

---

1. In the `values.yaml` file, I've configured the `podAffinity` as follows:

```
$ cat values.yaml
...
# Airflow scheduler settings
scheduler:  affinity:
    podAffinity:
      requiredDuringSchedulingIgnoredDuringExecution:
      - labelSelector:
          matchExpressions:
          - key: app
            operator: In
            values:
            - postgresql
        topologyKey: "kubernetes.io/hostname"
...
```

2. I've installed the [Airflow](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/helm-chart/stable/index.html#installing-the-chart) on a Kubernetes cluster using the Helm package manager with the `values.yaml` file specified.

```
$ helm install airflow apache-airflow/airflow --values values.yaml
```

After a while we can check the status of the `scheduler`:

```
$ kubectl get pods -owide | grep "scheduler"
airflow-scheduler-79bfb664cc-7n68f   0/2     Pending   0          8m6s   <none>      <none>                                 <none>           <none>
```

3. I've created an example Deployment with the `app: postgresql` label:

```
$ cat test.yaml
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  labels:
    app: postgresql
  name: test
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: postgresql
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: postgresql
    spec:
      containers:
      - image: nginx
        name: nginx
        
$ kubectl apply -f test.yaml
deployment.apps/test created

$ kubectl get pods --show-labels | grep test
test-7d4c9c654-7lqns                 1/1     Running   0          2m   app=postgresql,...
```

4. Finally, we can check that the `scheduler` was successfully created:

```
$ kubectl get pods -o wide | grep "scheduler\|test"
airflow-scheduler-79bfb664cc-7n68f   2/2     Running   0          14m     10.X.1.6    nodeA     
test-7d4c9c654-7lqns                 1/1     Running   0          2m27s   10.X.1.5    nodeA
```

---

Additionally, detailed informtion on `pod affinity` and `pod anti-affinity` can be found in the [Understanding pod affinity](https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/4.9/nodes/scheduling/nodes-scheduler-pod-affinity.html#nodes-scheduler-pod-affinity-about_nodes-scheduler-pod-affinity) documentation:

> Pod affinity and pod anti-affinity allow you to constrain which nodes your pod is eligible to be scheduled on based on the key/value labels on other pods.
>
> Pod affinity can tell the scheduler to locate a new pod on the same node as other pods if the label selector on the new pod matches the label on the current pod.
>
> Pod anti-affinity can prevent the scheduler from locating a new pod on the same node as pods with the same labels if the label selector on the new pod matches the label on the current pod.